# Как увеличить количество процессов в виртуальной машине? KVM

Tags: linux, windows, vmware, виртуализация, kvm

Не совсем понимаю. Что на VmWare, что на KVM похожая ситуация.
Windows 7.
Процессор на VmWare Xeon X5650. Выделено 2 сокета по 4 ядра на сокет. Итого 8.
Процессор на KVM i7-8700 CPU `<vcpu placement='static'>12</vcpu>`

В Диспетчере устройств - процессоры соответствую количеству, которое выдаю, а в "Система" - `Процессор: Intel(R) ... @GHz (2 процессора)`

Что не так? В частности интересует настройка KVM.

[image]

Comment: Ну как бы все правильно. "система" в windows показывает количество процессоров, а не количество ядер

Comment: @Mike но через диспетчер задач, я вижу на нормальной машине 8 процессоров, а в виртуалках только 2

Comment: Windows 7 работает максимум на 2х процессорах. Выставляйте один сокет и 8 ядер.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KVM выдает 8 сокетов системе, если не указать как распологаются ядра.

Windows 7 работает максимум на 2х процессорах. Выставляйте один сокет и 8 ядер.

Цитируя [ответ](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1ddf5515-815c-486f-9fcb-d18e0ab81196/how-many-cores-does-windows-7-support?forum=w7itprohardware):

Домашняя - один сокет, Проф - 2 сокета.

Comment: Моя виртуальная машина KVM настроена таким образом: `  <cpu mode='custom' match='exact' check='partial'>
    <model fallback='allow'>Skylake-Client-IBRS</model>
    <topology sockets='2' cores='4' threads='1'/>
  </cpu>`

Comment: не серверная винда капризная в этом плане. поищите кряк на это дело. сейчас покрутил-повертел - никак не принимает.

Comment: Cделал ````<vcpu placement='static'>8</vcpu>```` и ````<topology sockets='1' cores='8' threads='1'/>```` вижу в Диспетчере задач 8 ЦП

Comment: Не активированная 7ка волумка. Вроде проф. Вижу одно ядро в диспетчере как не крути) тут похоже все зависит от версий и вида релиза..